# Citations using biblatex-chicago strangely behaving

Tags: biblatex, citing, biblatex-chicago

I need to use Chicago 17th ed. style for my references. The code below does the job but the `\cite` command for in-text citations prints the full reference (as `\fullcite` is actually supposed to do).

What's wrong?

Here a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{bibfile.bib}

@article{gamow1946expanding,
    title={Expanding universe and the origin of elements},
    author={Gamow, George},
    journal={Physical Review},
    volume={70},
    number={7-8},
    pages={572},
    year={1946},
    publisher={APS}
}


\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}
\begin{document}

    \cite{gamow1946expanding}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is the output: 
[image]

Comment: You did not tell `biblatex-chicago` which style to use. Did you try something like `\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}` or `\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}`?

Comment: Off topic: Both `biblatex` and `biblatex-chicago` recommend `biber` as the backend, do you have a strong reason to use `backend=bibtex`?

Comment: @gusbrs using the `notes` option does not solve the problem. Regarding `backend`, actually I do not have any reason to opt for that and I can change it to `biber`. Did you run the code above and got the same output as mine?

Comment: Ah! I see what is likely going on! `notes` must be the default of `biblatex-chicago`. And, the first occurrence of a citation in that style is indeed similar to a bibliography entry and is expected to be given in footnote (with `\footcite`). To check if this is the case, test two things: 1) the `authordate` option (and you will see the citation format change); 2) with the `notes` option, change `cite` to `footcite` and add a second citation of the same bibentry (you will see the second instance as "ibid." or, if there's another between them, a short form).

Comment: What you suggest partially works. In fact, by using the `authordate` option I get Surname Year. However, there is not comma between the two and no parenthesis for the year. Could you suggest how to costumize the style?

Comment: You just have to choose the right citation command. `\cite` is the plain one. Try `\textcite` or `parencite` according to need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex-chicago`'s default is the `notes` style, which will render a full citation (bibliography like) on its first appearance and then a short version of it in subsequent citations (if not ibid.). This style is supposed to work with citations given in footnotes. So what you get is the expected result. If you'd like label-like citations to be given inline, you can use the `authordate` style of `biblatex-chicago` and then use `\textcite` or `\parencite` as needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{bibfile.bib}
@article{gamow1946expanding,
    title={Expanding universe and the origin of elements},
    author={Gamow, George},
    journal={Physical Review},
    volume={70},
    number={7-8},
    pages={572},
    year={1946},
    publisher={APS}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}

\begin{document}

\textcite{gamow1946expanding}

\parencite{gamow1946expanding}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]